# Challenging a granted patent?

Tags: validity, challenge, incorrect

I found a patent which was granted but the product which is claiming the patent is different from the contents of the patent.

How does one challenge the validity of the patent?

Answer (score 1):

A patent can be challenged in an ex party re-examination or an *inter partes* review at the USPTO. They are expensive procedures. In this case you are concerned about a difference between a product and its description in a patent. That would *not* be grounds for challenging the patent. A patent owner has no obligation to make a product that matches any description or definition in their patent. Also, the maker of a product does not need to have a patent at all, let along one that matches a manufactured product.

If the product has a patent number printed on it, that is another issue. There is a law against mis-marking of products with a non-applicable or expired patent. However the America Invents Act ("AIA") took the teeth out of it.